# adding resolver to angular routeProvider in config

Tags: angularjs, service, boilerplate, resolver

i start working with angular 1.x boilerplate and have 1 problem, i can`t send into resolver promise from service

```
function ExampleService($http) {
'ngInject';

const service = {};
let getTasks = ()=> {
    return $http.get('tasks');
};

service.isReady = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    getTasks().then(
        (data) => {
            resolve(data);
        },
        (err, status) => {
            reject(err, status);
        });
});

return service;
```

}

export default {
    name: 'ExampleService',
    fn: ExampleService
};
But when i try inject ,y service to on_config.js i have error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ExampleService

My stateProvider

```
$stateProvider
    .state('Home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl as home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    title: 'Home',
    resolve:{example:ExampleService.isReady}
    })
```

Maybe i do something wrong or you can suggest how can i impelemt logic for preloading some data to app before rendering first controller

P.S. link to [bolerplate](https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate)

Comment: Make sure You register service with following code `angular.module('app').service(ExampleService)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services can't be injected into config blocks. They need to be injected in resolver functions:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('Home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl as home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    title: 'Home',
    resolve:{
       example: function (ExampleService) {
           return ExampleService.isReady();
       }
    })
```

Also the `isReady` needs to be a function, not a new promise:

```
service.isReady = () => {
    return getTasks().then(response => response.data);
}
```

Comment: thank you, it`s really help me, but could you explain (or give links with explanation) why isReady should be a function